# A paste action on an exe of cmd file starts it. Can this behavior be prevented?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Everyone knows that if you select an exe file in File Explorer (former Windows Explorer) and apply the "paste" action, the exe file starts and the "pasted" file name is used as the exe command line argument.
However, this behavior can be very annoying. If I select a group of exe files, right click on it and mistakenly hit "Paste" instead of "Copy" it can be a little disaster.
So, the question is: can this "paste on an executable file" behavior be turned off?

Comment: As I can see, my question is the most difficult one ever been asked here...